# How to wait until io.to().emit() is finished in Javascript

Tags: node.js, sockets, async-await, promise, socket.io

I have a function that needs to wait for an io.to().emit() call to finish on the client side before continuing.

I've tried implementations with Promises to try and use await with the function:

```
await io.to(socketID).emit("request", { var1: val1, var2: val2 })
```

I think it doesn't work because there's still no way to wait for the io.to().emit() before resolving. Not sure what standard practice for this really is because acknowledgements are only available to socket instances, not the io instance.

```
const ioEmitFunction = function(id, object) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      io.to(id).emit("request", object);
      resolve("Resolved")
  })
}

ioEmitFunction(socketID, { var1: val1, var2: val2 }).then((value) => {
  //callback here after this stuff is done
})
```

I've also tried implementing custom callbacks...this also doesn't seem to work as intended because there's no way of continuing the function when the "request" emission is finished on the client side. Not sure what exactly I'm supposed to do here, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Socket.io does not offer anything that tells you when `io.to(...).emit(...)` has been received by all the destinations.  What is the problem you're really trying to solve here?  In other words, why are you trying to "wait".  If you really want to know when everyone has received the message, you will have to send the messages individually with acknowledgements and keep track of when all the acknowledgements have been received.  As with all networking, that will be non-blocking and asynchronous.

Comment: const ioEmitFunction = function(id, object) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      io.to(id).emit("request", object, resolve);
  })
}

consider trying this, this works on client if the server sends the acknowledgment and runs forever if the server does not respond, so I had to set up a timeout mechanism. Don't know if it works for server as well.

Comment: @ShahriarShojib What exactly do I do with the resolve on the client side once it has been passed to the emission?

Comment: @jfriend00 Essentially, I have a function on a Heroku deployed app that does some Postgres table operations, and then I use io.to().emit() to establish deliver some data to a web scraping function set up on a raspberry pi (because Heroku doesn't allow scraping). In the function on the pi, I'm running some more table operations. Essentially, I'm using client.query() with 'BEGIN', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK,' so I need to only COMMIT once the raspberry pi function is finished, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to create some kind of acknowledgement/callback/await for when the io.to.emit is done

Comment: As I said above, you will need to not use `io.to(...).emit(...)` as it does not support acknowledgement.  Instead, you will have to send the messages individually with acknowledgement and count the acknowledgements so you know when they have all been received.  You will probably also need to implement some sort of timeout because if a raspberry Pi is temporarily down or disconnected, you may not get an acknowledgement for a very, very long time.

Comment: @jfriend00 The pi in this case is acting as a client, so how would I just send to that specific socket? Normally, you have an 'onConnection' function with a socket in the parameters and then you are able to run socket.to.emit, but if my function is outside of the onConnection function, how can I access the RPi client socket?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `io.to(...).emit(...)` as it does not support acknowledgement. Instead, you will have to send the messages individually with acknowledgement and count the acknowledgements so you know when they have all been received. You will probably also need to implement some sort of timeout because if a raspberry Pi is temporarily down or disconnected, you may not get an acknowledgement for a very, very long time.

In the latest version of socket.io, if you just have one socket, you're trying to do this with, you can get that one socket like this:

```
const sockets = await io.in(socketId).fetchSockets();
if (sockets.length) {
    // should only be one socket in the array since we used a single socketId as the room indicator
    const piSocket = sockets[0];
    piSocket.emit(msg, data, (response) => {
        // response has been received
    });
}
```

You could, of course, wrap this in a promise if that was helpful for the control flow.  And, you should probably add a timeout.

---

If this app is pretty much hard-coded to only use one Pi socket, you could also just stuff the Pi socket object into a module-level variable anytime it connects and then you'd already have the Pi socket object available anywhere in that module.  It appears you may already be doing that with the socketID.

Comment: I tried changing it just a bit. Wrapped it in a promise, resolved inside the callback. But then I realized the emission is coming from the client side (piSocket) back to the server. I need it the other way around, where it's emission from the server to the pi side with a callback. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @nickcoding2 - I don't understand what you mean by "the other way around".  If you emit a message to the client with acknowledgement, then your server will get notified when the client acknowledges receipt of that message.

Comment: Right, but piSocket.emit(msg, data (response) => {}) emits from the client to the server. I need to emit from the server to the piSocket, which is why I was originally using io.to.emit--sorry if I'm fundamentally not understanding something.

Comment: @nickcoding2 - No, `piSocket` in my example is the server-side socket object for the connection to the raspeberryPi.  `piSocket.emit()` sends a message from the server to the raspberryPi and uses an acknowledgement callback to know when the Pi says it is done receiving the message.

Comment: Got it, thank you--my mistake was not implementing a callback on the Pi-side that is necessary for there to be a response in the acknowledgement. It works like a charm!